# Add new div in a nested HTML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure and code:

```
<ul class="navMore">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li href="#"><a>Link 2</a><?li>
</ul>

<div class="row-fluid"></div>


$(".navMore li a").each(function() {
   $(this).on("click", function() {
        $('<div class="row-fluid"></div>').insertAfter($(this).closest('.row-fluid'));
        $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').insertAfter($(this).next('.row-fluid'));
   });
});
```

I need to add a new `.row-fluid` div just after the previous `.row-fluid`

Expected result:

```
<ul class="navMore">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li href="#"><a>Link 2</a><?li>
</ul>
<div class="row-fluid"></div>
<div class="row-fluid"></div>
```

But if we already added a new `.row-fluid` div, then the `#content` div should be put inside this newly added `row-fluid` div

How do I achieve this?

```
<ul class="navMore">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li href="#"><a>Link 2</a><?li>
</ul>
    <div class="row-fluid"></div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="content" class="span4"></div>
    </div>
```

Finally, how can I do that if we have inserted 3 `#content` div, start again with a new `.row-fluid` div and all again?

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).closest('.row-fluid').after('<div class="row-fluid"></div>');`

Comment: thanks but what about the "after 3 div" issue?

Comment: How would you know whether or not a row-fluid is "new" or not?

Comment: preceisly, that's to resolve too

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navMore li a").click(function() {

    var countOfDiv = $(".row-fluid").length;
    if(countOfDiv < 2)
            $('<div class="row-fluid"></div>').insertAfter(".row-fluid");
    else
        $(".row-fluid:last").html("<div id=\"content\" class=\"span4\"></div>");
    });
});

</script>
```

Link 1

Link 2

Comment: to escape the other double quote.  I believe that you can just use single quotes around the whole thing then double inside.

Comment: not really working as expected as it is loading the new row-fluid div just after any new added row div, but if you look at my code I need to first add a new row-fluid div after the link then run the other code

Comment: Look at the final html structure I am looking to achieve in my question

Comment: Can you please restate what you are looking for?  The first click will insert a row-fluid div after the other one.  The second click will find the last row-fluid and will add the div with id=content inside it.  Here is the full page, you can save as html and open it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".navMore li a").click(function() {

var countOfDiv = $(".row-fluid").length;
if(countOfDiv < 2)
  $('<div class="row-fluid"></div>').insertAfter(".row-fluid");
else
 $(".row-fluid:last").html("<div id=\"content\" class=\"span4\"></div>");
});
});

</script>

<ul class="navMore">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="row-fluid"></div>

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertRow() {
    $newdiv = $("<div class='row-fluid'/>");
    $newdiv.insertAfter(".row-fluid:last");
    return $newdiv;
}

// assume you're passing a content object into the routine
function insertContent( contentObj) {
    $lastRow = $(".row-fluid:last");
    if( $lastRow.children().length >= 3) {
        insertRow().append( contentObj);
    } else {
        $lastRow.append( contentObj);
    }
    return contentObj;
}
```

Comment: how would I run this with a menu item click? Needs to be outputting exactly as per my last ideal html structure on my question

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I went with this:

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var $row = $el.closest('.row');
  if($row.next('.new').length){
     $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
  }
  else {
    $('<div class="new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
    $('<div class="span"></div>').appendTo('.new');
  }
});
```